# How do I continuously rotate a model during OrbitAnimation so that the model is facing forward?

Tags: swift, swiftui, realitykit

I am trying to animate a bicycle so that it rides around in a circle. Right now I have

```
transform.translation = [0.5, 0, 0]
// Define an orbit animation
let animationDefinition = OrbitAnimation(duration: 5, axis: [0, 1, 0], startTransform: transform, bindTarget: .transform, repeatMode: AnimationRepeatMode.repeat)
let animationResource = try! AnimationResource.generate(with: animationDefinition)
scene.playAnimation(animationResource)
```

The problem is that the bike does not face forward. Rather it looks like it's on a turntable.

I tried to blend a rotation with `BlendTreeAnimation` but that doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out there's an easy built in way to do this using `orientToPath`. Just pass that to `OrbitAnimation` and set it to `true`.

```
let animationDefinition = OrbitAnimation(duration: 5, axis: [0, 1, 0], startTransform: transform, orientToPath: true, bindTarget: .transform, repeatMode: AnimationRepeatMode.repeat)
```

Now the bike always faces forward relative to its current position on the orbit.